# Find a Specific Cell entry in a Column in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on creating a userform for reviewing an excel sheet. I need to search a specific column to see if the user has already reviewed the row. If they have, the cell will be filled with "Reviewed", if it hasn't been reviewed yet it will have "Not Reviewed" in it.

Each department has their own Column logging whether the Row has been reviewed or not. I.e. Dept1 may have reviewed the row, while Dept2 has not yet.

I've tried something like

```
    With Sheets("ECR")
        UnReviewedRow = .Range(DepartmentReviewColumn:DepartmentReviewColumn).Find(what:="Not Reviewed", after:=.Cells(DepartmentReviewColumn, 3)).Row
    End With
```

But I'm getting an error, not quite sure where it's coming from though. The hardcoded "3" is because I know that all entries begin at row three, everything above is headers.

I've found a few different similar questions, but they all assume that the column being searched will be the same every time. My issue is that I don't want to code this for each department, I'd like to be a bit more elegant than that.

Comment: Cells is row, column not column, row

Comment: `.Range(DepartmentReviewColumn:DepartmentReviewColumn)` looks like a problem.  What's the value of `DepartmentReviewColumn`?

Comment: also assuming DepartmentReviewColumn a string and would need concatenating properly? DepartmentReviewColumn & ":"  &DepartmentReviewColumn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
With Sheets("ECR")
    UnReviewedRow = .Range(DepartmentReviewColumn & ":" & DepartmentReviewColumn).Find(What:="Not Reviewed", After:=.Cells(3, DepartmentReviewColumn)).Row
End With
```

Modifications made:

- Range() now takes a properly built string argument;
- Cells() now has a row number as its first argument, and a column expressed as a string as its second argument.

Note that this code will fail with `Object variable or With block variable not set` if the search string is not found. You can handle this situation by initializing UnReviewedRow to e.g. 0 (zero) and putting `On Error Resume Next` above the Find call, and `On Error Resume <either 0 or your original error handler's label>` below the Find call. Then, check if UnReviewedRow = 0 and act appropriately.

Always put Option Explicit at the top of modules and classes, and compile your code (Debug / Compile VBAProject). When posting, include the text of all errors encountered.